# Matching function condition to media query

Tags: jquery

This might be pretty obvious but I'm a bit stumped.

I have a media query in CSS that changes styles based on the window size:

```
@media screen and (max-width:39.9375em) {
  ...
}
```

I need to write a jQuery function to also execute when the screen size is below the size mentioned in media query. How do I do that?

```
function matchScreen() {
    if ($(window).innerWidth() < ???) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `window` `resize` event and, in your handler, use [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to check if you have a match for that media query.

E.g., along these lines:

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width:39.9375em)").matches) {
        // It's a match
    } else {
        // It's not a match
    }
});
```

You can also use an event callback from `matchMedia`:

```
window.matchMedia("(max-width:39.9375em)").addListener(function(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
        // It's a match
    } else {
        // It's not a match
    }
});
```

...which I suspect (but don't *know*) is more efficient.

Either way, you may want to debounce that a bit if what you're doing in the branches causes resizing to lag.

Comment: Wow, never saw this one. Will this work with jQuery?

Comment: @santa - Yes, the first example above is using jQuery. See also the updated answer, I'd forgotten `matchMedia` has an option to provide a callback (and I'd left `.matches` off the first example).